# i want to create a data table in single visualization in Kibana using 2 index's

Tags: elasticsearch, datatable, kibana, elastic-stack, multi-index

I want to create a data table in a single visualization in Kibana that combines data from two different indexes into a single visualization. In Kibana elastic search

I want to make a data table visualization using two different index's.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMAqo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMAqo.png)

Answer (score 0):

To search/visualize your data in multiple indices via Kibana UI you can create index_pattern with start (*) in data **view/index pattern**.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/data-views.html#settings-create-pattern

Start typing in the Index pattern field, and Kibana looks for the names of indices, data streams, and aliases that match your input. You can view all available sources or only the sources that the data view targets.

##### Create data view

> To match multiple sources, use a wildcard (*). filebeat-* matches
> filebeat-apache-a, filebeat-apache-b, and so on. To match multiple
> single sources, enter their names, separated by a comma. Do not
> include a space after the comma. filebeat-a,filebeat-b matches two
> indices. To exclude a source, use a minus sign (-), for example,
> -test3.

[image]

Comment: so as of now I have 2 index with the name merchant_master and 2nd is amex_service Do you means that I should keep merchant_master* like this it what about the amex_service index? I want to show visualization in data table form of both the index at a time

Comment: Definitely! Keeping the indices name in one format would be the best option. For quick solution you can add same alias to both indices and use as a index pattern. To add an alias you can check this documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: Thank you for this. but when I have to create a data table in visualization should I keep both index's together like index1,index2 or alone like index1 in kibana in the management section

Comment: as of now indice name is the same so I created one index with the name of amex*  when i am making a data table of that in visualization then only one index data is showing  and when taking value from other index of whch is there in drop section of filed then it show no result found Here i am stuck to show data's of second index at a time showing only one index's data's

Comment: Make sure both indices have **the same field names** otherwise when you filter the unrelated indices will show no result.

Comment: yes i check both indice have same filed name but still getting no result

Comment: Please add a couple of screenshot to understand it better and let me try to help more

Comment: i have add i request to you to see it

Comment: there is only one screenshot and there is no data in it. Are you sure that the index pattern hits any index?

Comment: yes becasue i have added 2 index in this with same alice name if i will only show one index data then it show else it will show this kind of message

Comment: from devtools `GET amex*/_search`, and `GET _cat/indices/amex*?v`

Comment: i did not get you

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html